# UITabBarController is possible to select the tab via code?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

is it UITabBarController possible to select the tab in code?like UINavigationController
we can use popViewController pop back to rootViewController instead of press the back button, so how can this implement in tabbarcontroller?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use the selectedIndex property on the UITabBarController. More information can be found in the [UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedIndex).

`controller.selectedIndex = 4;`

or use

`[controller setSelectedIndex:4];`

Comment: that should be [controller setSelectedIndex:4]

Comment: But that code doesn't trigger tabBarController:didSelectViewController:

Comment: If you want to use the delegate method to do work, you could just call it yourself using `self.tabController(tabController, didSelect: controller)`. A bit hacky but it works. You should file a radar for it; setting the index _should_ call it automatically.