# setSelectedIndex has no effect on UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I'm attempting to add view controllers to my `tabbarcontroller`, and then make the first one the selected one using the following code:

```
[self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.detailController,self.mapController,nil] animated:NO];
[self setSelectedIndex:0];
```

When this code is called, the correct view controllers/tabs are added, but none are selected.
Is there a better way to do this?

Update: To add more context, the above code snippet is being called in the `viewDidLoad` method of a `view controller` that subclasses `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem, and using the following code seemed to help. Essentially, it adds a delayed reaction to the change. Sorry for the four year delay in response :)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self setSelectedIndex:2];
});
```

Comment: @midas06 that might help^

Answer (score 0):

[UITabBarController is possible to select the tab via code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833389/uitabbarcontroller-is-possible-to-select-the-tab-via-code)

looks like it answers you question based on the code you have provided; if not can you show the code in context?

Comment: That other question says the same thing im currently doing. The trick is the controller isn't responding.