# Popping from one viewcontroller to tab bar viewcontroller of index 0

Tags: swift

How to pop from one viewcontroller to tab bar viewcontroller of index 0 in swift. I dont know where to use tabBar.selectedindex = 0 and how to pop from current viewcontroller. If I am poping it goes to the tabBarViewcontroller of index 2 where i made push actually. This is the code I used when popping,

```
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as! [UIViewController]
self.navigationController!.popToViewController(viewControllers[1], animated: true).
```

Comment: actually it is not one, it is zero'th index  ->popToViewController(viewControllers[0], ....)

Answer (score 1):

Revise your code like so:

```
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as! [UIViewController]
self.navigationController!.popToViewController(viewControllers.first(), animated: true)
```

Comment: The above revised code is to pop safely but I did not get the answer yet

Comment: I did not get the question.

Comment: I navigate from ThirdTabBarViewController to a NewViewController(I achieved). Now I am trying to navigate from NewViewController to FirstTabBarViewController

Comment: This is the link. https://www.draw.io/#LVcToTabBarVcOfZerothIndex.xml where I want to go from NewViewController to TabBarItemVC0. Hope now you got the question @jovit.royeca

Comment: If you have a reference to the `UITabBarController`, you cat use set its selectedIndex. Perhaps you can refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833389/uitabbarcontroller-is-possible-to-select-the-tab-via-code